# How does ROS2 select the default QoS profile?

Tags: ros, ros2, xml, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS2 based python code, which mentions nothing about the QoS Settings. I assume that it must be taking some default profile.

How can I view this default profile ? I mean where is the source of this profile ? Is it xml based ? Can I also edit it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298594/how-does-ros2-select-the-default-qos-profile-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The defaults are defined [here in `rmw`](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/8ea66dbbe89e78318cd2f2b4e7d8da51211d67bb/rmw/include/rmw/qos_profiles.h), and are [described here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings). The default profiles are wrapped accordingly in `rclpy` ([example](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/82ac34316e42937d3f4418d26b8784687892f820/demo_nodes_py/demo_nodes_py/topics/talker_qos.py#L66)), or you can customise the QoS settings [like this](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/58450594268e1540490239db31dcb413e37288b8/topic_monitor/topic_monitor/scripts/data_publisher.py#L73). Some RMW implementations support xml file configuration in which case the `rmw_qos_profile_system_default` profile can be used to pass through to that configuration.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-07-25**:
Thanks for the quick explanation @dhood.
One question : If nothing at all is mentioned in the code(about QoS settings), e.g. `talker.py`, does it always use the default QoS or does it mean that it doesnt use any QoS in this case ?

**Comment by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) on 2018-07-25**:
without it being specified, pub/sub will use the profile `rmw_qos_profile_default`, services will use `rmw_qos_profile_services_default`, etc.

**Comment by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on 2021-10-22**:
which doers `rviz` use? I am assuming `rmw_qos_profile_default`, I have a lidar for example where the points are invisible unless i manually change the QoS to best effort.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those who are lazy like myself, plus it's not really covered in the tutorials, here's how you specify the QoS for a topic subscription.

```
  twist_stamped_sub_ =
      node_->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::TwistStamped>(parameters_->cartesian_command_in_topic,
                                                                   rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS(),
                                                                   std::bind(&ServoCalcs::twistStampedCB, this, _1));
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1